# Por que não posso usar o método delete() do StringBuilder mais de uma vez no mesmo bloco de código?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Estou tentando apagar um intervalo de conteúdo de uma `StringBuilder`, mas ao usar o método `delete()` mais de uma vez o programa dá erro.

Especificamente, estou tentando deletar a parte da resolução em pseudocódigo de algumas questões de um livro virtual, deixando apenas o enunciado.
Há um padrão no momento de início dos pseudocódigos, pois iniciam com **prog** e termina com **fimprog**. Observe o exemplo abaixo:

```
algoritmo 362
Criar um algoritmo que leia dois conjuntos de números inteiros, tendo cada
284 um 10 e 20 elementos, e apresente os elementos comuns aos conjuntos. Lembre-se de que os elementos podem se repetir, mas não podem aparecer repetidos na saída.
prog vetorl10

pseudocógigos...

fimprog

algoritmo 363
Criar um algoritmo que leia vários números inteiros e positivos. A leitura se en-
cerra quando encontrar um número negativo ou quando o vetor ficar completo.
Sabe-se que o vetor possui, no máximo, 10 elementos. Gerar e imprimir um vetor
onde cada elemento é o inverso do correspondente do vetor original.
prog vetorl11

pseudocógigos...

fimprog

algoritmo364...
```

Etapas do código:

- O programa ler um arquivo;
- Coloca o conteúdo em uma `StringBuilder`;
- O programa pega o índice inicial da palavra "prog" e da "fimprog";
- O programa chama o método delete e apaga o conteúdo dos intervalos definidos;
- O programa pega novamente o próximo índice da palavra "prog" e da "fimprog" e consegue, mas na hora de apagar o próximo intervalo dá erro.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Character.Subset;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class BuscarPadroes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "c:\\socket\\Lista_vetor.txt";

        String line;
        StringBuilder conteudo = new StringBuilder();
        int cont = 0;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {

            while (br.ready()) {
                line = br.readLine();
                cont++;
                conteudo.append(line + "\n");
            }
            
            
            int start = conteudo.indexOf("prog");
            int end = conteudo.indexOf("fimprog");
            conteudo.delete(start, end);
            
            start = conteudo.indexOf("prog ");
            end = conteudo.indexOf("fimprog");
            conteudo.delete(start, end);

        } catch (IOException erro) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + erro.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem vários problemas aí. O primeiro já foi indicado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469245/112052): `indexOf` retorna o índice onde **começa** a ocorrência da substring. Ou seja, `conteudo.indexOf("fimprog")` vai retornar a posição onde começa a string "fimprog", o que quer dizer que "fimprog" não será removido de fato, pois [segundo a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,int)), o segundo índice não é incluso (por exemplo, `delete(1, 4)` apaga as posições 1, 2 e 3). Ou seja, "fimprog" não é removido, e na segunda vez que você busca, ele estará antes de "prog", ou seja `start` será maior que `end` - e a documentação diz que nesse caso dá erro.

Então você tem que pegar mais 7 posições à frente (ou 8 se quiser eliminar também a quebra de linha), mas ainda tem outros problemas. Seu código foi feito de forma que só busca duas ocorrências de "prog" e "fimprog", mas e se tiver mais (ou menos - o que inclui o caso de não ter nenhuma)? E se só tiver "prog" sem o respectivo "fimprog"? Etc...

Enfim, para um caso mais geral, seria melhor fazer um *loop*. Enquanto tiver "prog" e "fimprog", vai removendo. Quando não tiver mais, sai do *loop*:

```
while (true) {
    int start = conteudo.indexOf("prog");
    if (start < 0) {
        // não tem prog, nem adianta continuar
        break;
    }
    int end = conteudo.indexOf("fimprog");
    if (end < 0) {
        // não tem fimprog, nem adianta continuar
        break;
    }
    if (start > end) {
        System.out.println("texto mal formado, prog está depois de fimprog");
        break; // texto mal formado, nem adianta continuar
    }
    // somar o tamanho de "fimprog", senão ela não é apagada
    conteudo.delete(start, end + 7);
}
```

---

## Invertendo a lógica

Mas na verdade, eu acho que isso tudo é desnecessário. Em vez de jogar o texto inteiro para uma `String` e depois sair buscando e removendo alguns trechos, não seria melhor simplesmente **não adicionar os trechos que você não quer**?

Assumindo que "prog" e "fimprog" sempre estão no início da linha, ficaria assim:

```
boolean adiciona = true;
while (br.ready()) {
    line = br.readLine();
    if (line.startsWith("prog")) {
        adiciona = false;
    } else if (line.startsWith("fimprog")) {
        adiciona = true;
    } else if (adiciona) {
        conteudo.append(line + "\n");
    }
}
```

Ou seja, se encontro "prog", eu ignoro todas as linhas dali em diante, até encontrar "fimprog" (e aí eu volto a adicionar as linhas, até que encontre um "prog" novamente). O detalhe é que neste caso não estou verificando se o arquivo está mal formado (se só tiver um "prog" e não tiver o respectivo "fimprog", por exemplo, todo o restante do arquivo depois desse "prog" será ignorado). Se existe essa possibilidade, aí a primeira opção acima seria melhor (ou, dependendo do caso, talvez seja o caso de fazer um *parser* próprio para validar). Mas se é "garantido" que o arquivo é sempre bem formado, eu acho melhor fazer assim, em vez de adicionar tudo para depois ir removendo.

Comment: Poxa, muito obrigado. Era exatamente a lógica inversa que eu tentei fazer, porém, não consegui e resolvi tentar dessa maneira. Detalhe, eu coloquei duas ocorrências para teste e por falta de uma compreensão melhor do indexOf. Voltarei a ler a documentação do método.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na lógica do seu delete. O método `indexOf` retornará o índice do começo da palavra, então você precisa considerar o tamanho da palavra ao passar para o método `delete`. Se não fizer isso, na segunda iteração a palavra "fimprog" estará antes da palavra "prog", causando erro.

```
int start = conteudo.indexOf("prog");
int end = conteudo.indexOf("fimprog") + "fimprog".length();
conteudo.delete(start, end);
```

Para mais detalhes consulte a documentação da classe StringBuilder: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: Ótimo. Eu compreendi o método indexOf de outra maneira, mesmo lendo a documentação. Muito obrigado!